# Sorting when there are only O(log n) many different numbers

Tags: algorithms, sorting

We have $n$ integers with lot's of repeated numbers. In this list, the number of distinct elements is $O(\log n)$. What's the best asymptotic number of comparisons for sorting this list?

Any idea or hint or pseudo code? In fact I want to learn pseudo code.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? For instance, which of the well-known sorting algorithms are affected by duplicates, and have you ideas on how to fix those that are? Do you have reason to believe that you can do any better?

Comment: Regarding the question: do you allow algorithms *tailored* to this situation, or do they have to perform within certain bounds in general, too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you asked for minimum number of comparisons, so I assume the algorithm can only compare the numbers.

The idea is to extend the [sorting lower bound](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf) argument.
Assume you want to sort $n$ elements knowing there exist at most $k$ distinct values. There are $n!$ ways to permute the elements, but many of them are equivalent. If there are $n_i$ element of the $i$th values. Each permutation is equivalent to $\prod_{i=1}^k n_i!$ other permutations. So the total number of distinct permutations is

$$\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^k n_i!}$$

The number of required comparisons is bounded below by $$ \log_2 \left( n!/\min \{ \prod_{i=1}^k n_i! \big| \sum_{i=1}^k n_i = n, n_i\geq 0\text{ for all } i\} \right)$$

Good thing that minimization part can be [easily shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/565554) by extend factorial to the continuous domain. $\min \{ \prod_{i=1}^k n_i! \big| \sum_{i=1}^k n_i = n, n_i\geq 0\text{ for all } i\}$ is attained when $n_i=n/k$. (note the $\log$ in the next computation is base $e$ for convenience)

$$ \log \left( n!/{(n/k)!^k} \right) = \log (n!) - k \log ((n/k)!) = n\log(n) - n\log(n/k) + O(\log n)=  n(\log(n)-\log(n)+\log(k)) + O(\log n) = \Omega(n\log k) $$

$\log(n!) = n\log n - n + O(\log n)$ is [Ramanujan's approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152342/ramanujans-approximation-to-factorial).

To get an upper bound. Just consider storing the unique values in a binary search tree, and each insert we either increase the number of occurrence of an element in the BST, or insert a new element into the BST. Finally, print the output from the BST. This would take $O(n\log k)$ time.

Since both the lower bound and upper bound works for all $k$, the algorithm would take $O(n\log \log n)$ time for your problem.

**Addendum:**

I just figured out from @Pseudonym's comment that this proof also proves that we need at least $nH$ comparisons where $H$ is the entropy of the alphabet, so I might as well add this to the answer.

Let $c = \log 2$ and $p_i = n_i/n$. The entropy of the alphabet where the $i$th letter appears $n_i$ time is $H=-\sum p_i \log_2 p_i$. $nH = -\sum n_i (\log_2(n_i)-\log_2(n)) = \sum n_i (\log_2(n) - \log_2(n_i)) = c \sum n_i (\log(n) - \log(n_i))$.

\begin{align*}
\log_2 \left( n!/\prod_{i=1}^k n_i! \right) &= \log_2(n!)-\sum_{i=1}^k \log_2(n_i!)  \\
&= \log_2(n!)-\sum_{i=1}^k \log_2(n_i!)  \\
&= c (\log(n!)-\sum_{i=1}^k \log(n_i!))  \\
&= c (n \log n-n + O(\log n) - \sum_{i=1}^k n_i \log(n_i)-n_i+O(\log n_i))  \\
&\geq c (n \log n-n -  \sum_{i=1}^k n_i \log(n_i)-n_i)  \\
&= c (-n + \sum_{i=1}^k n_i(\log(n) - \log(n_i))+n_i)  \\
&= c (\sum_{i=1}^k n_i(\log(n) - \log(n_i)))  \\
&= nH
\end{align*}

Comment: Great answer! One thing I'd add: If you want a practical algorithm, Bentley & McIlroy's variant of quicksort with ternary partitioning would achieve this lower bound for this type of problem (for non-pathological input, because this is quicksort we're talking about). http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.8162

Comment: One more thing while I think about it. There's a useful theorem that comparison-based sorting takes at least $nH - n$ comparisons, where $H$ is the entropy of the key distribution. That's another way to derive this result.

Comment: $H = \sum_i -p_i \log p_i$ where $i$ ranges over the unique keys and $p_i$ is the probability that an element has key $i$. If there are $\log n$ unique keys distributed evenly, then $p_i = \frac{1}{\log n}$, and so $H = \sum_{i=1}^{\log n} - \frac{1}{\log n} \log \frac{1}{\log n} = \log \log n$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for $nH-n$ lowerbound? I got that we must use at least $nH$ comparisons. I might have missed something.

Comment: Nice proof! Very elegant. IIRC, the $-n$ term probably comes from using more terms in Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @ChaoXu Munro and Spira gave such an entropy lower bound (and analyzed the variants of various sorting algorithms to give a matching upper bound)  in 1976: https://sci-hub.ru/10.1137/0205001