# Number of comparisons in array where each element appears n/k times

Tags: sorting, arrays, lower-bounds

Given an array of $n$ elements with $k$ distinct elements, each appearing $n/k$ times, how can I show that the number of comparisons to the sort the array in the worst case is in $\Omega(n \log k)$?

Comment: This question should have been asked before on this site. How much have you tried searching using the search bar at the top of the page?

Comment: The condition "each appearing $n/k$ times" can be removed. You can consider this as a hint.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please demonstrate your effort in the question.

Comment: Hint: how many ways are there to arrange n/k copies of k distinct elements? You only need an asymptotic lower bound.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting when there are only O(log n) many different numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29195/sorting-when-there-are-only-olog-n-many-different-numbers/29199#29199), where the answer deals with the general situation of $k$ distinct elements.